# Round all digits in a Array

Tags: powershell

I've got a Question. I have a Script which gets everybodys Usernames and there sums der pst Files and puts out a Table with all Users and the Size of all ther pst Files in GB.

```
$Gesamt = Get-ChildItem $Verzeichniss |Select-Object Name,@{Name='TotalSizeInGB';Expression={ (Get-ChildItem -Path $Verzeichniss$($_.Name)\ , $Verzeichniss$($_.Name)\Archiv\ , $Verzeichniss$($_.Name)\Outlook\ -Filter *$($FileType) | Measure Length -Sum).Sum /1.GB}}  | Sort-Object -Property TotalSizeInGB -Descending | Select-Object -Property Name,TotalSizeInGB -First 30
```

My Problem now is that the size of the pst files is about 10 digits long after the ".". But I don't know how i maybe can make it only 2 digits long after the ".". Do you guys have a idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using round, like so

```
$a = 111.2226
[math]::Round($a,2)
```

will give you: 111.22 and

```
[math]::Round($a)
```

will give you: 111

**Solution:**

```
$Gesamt = Get-ChildItem $Verzeichniss |Select-Object Name,@{Name='TotalSizeInGB';Expression={ [math]::Round(((Get-ChildItem -Path $Verzeichniss$($_.Name)\ , $Verzeichniss$($_.Name)\Archiv\ , $Verzeichniss$($_.Name)\Outlook\ -Filter *$($FileType) | Measure Length -Sum).Sum /1.GB),2)}}  | Sort-Object -Property TotalSizeInGB -Descending | Select-Object -Property Name,TotalSizeInGB -First 30
```

Modify the query accordingly.

ref: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-powershell-to-round-to-specific-decimal-place/

Comment: I no did
```
[math]::round(($Gesamt.TotalSizeInGB),2)
```
But then it ecourse a error. "Cannot find an overload for “Round” and the argument count: “2”."

Comment: I have just given you the possible solution. It worked for me: >> 
$Gesamt = Get-ChildItem $Verzeichniss |Select-Object Name,@{Name='TotalSizeInGB';Expression={ [math]::Round(((Get-ChildItem -Path $Verzeichniss$($_.Name)\ , $Verzeichniss$($_.Name)\Archiv\ , $Verzeichniss$($_.Name)\Outlook\ -Filter *$($FileType) | Measure Length -Sum).Sum /1.GB),2)}}  | Sort-Object -Property TotalSizeInGB -Descending | Select-Object -Property Name,TotalSizeInGB -First 30

Comment: Perfect. Thats exactly what I needed ;)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a display problem, then you can use [string formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-fixed-point-f-format-specifier) to get you there

```
$Gesamt = Get-ChildItem $Verzeichniss |Select-Object Name,@{Name='TotalSizeInGB';Expression={ (Get-ChildItem -Path $Verzeichniss$($_.Name)\ , $Verzeichniss$($_.Name)\Archiv\ , $Verzeichniss$($_.Name)\Outlook\ -Filter *$($FileType) | Measure Length -Sum).Sum /1.GB}}  | Sort-Object -Property TotalSizeInGB -Descending | Select-Object -Property Name,TotalSizeInGB -First 30
```

Output results using format string specifying digits

```
$Gesamt | ForEach-Object { Write-Output ( 'Name: {0}; Total Size(GB): {1:F2}' -f $_.Name, $_.TotalSizeInGB ) }
```